# Accumulate the gradient on all conditions before or after backpropagating

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

I have been working on coding a simple Neural Network, and I have come across a question that I would like to discuss with you. I am trying to approximate two functions with the Neural Network: $f_1(x) = x^2$ and $f_2(x) = (1-x)^2$. To calculate the local losses, I am using the following equations:

$L_1 = \|NN(x) - x^2\|$ and $L_2 = \|NN(x) - (1 - x^2)\|$

My question is regarding the optimization process. Should I perform the optimization for each condition separately and not cumulatively? Or should I accumulate the gradient on all conditions before backpropagating? I am not sure which approach would be more appropriate?

[image]

Comment: _accumulate the gradient on all conditions_ what does it mean? what are "conditions"?

Comment: I use the term 'condition' to refer to the local losses. My question is whether you sum them before the optimization step, or if you treat each local loss separately during optimization.

Comment: you definitely have to sum the two, otherwise the gradient is not representative of your actual gradient (you are going otherwise to do a step to optimize one loss and then another for the second one, thus potentially never converging)